# how to add a 2 weeks internship in my linkedIn profile

Tags: linkedin

I had an internship during spring break that lasted 2 weeks. but I don't know how to add it to my LinkedIn profile in the experience section, since the smallest period is at least 1 month.

Thank in advance for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the internship was useful experience you want on your CV, just add it in to your profile as a month, and in the description write:

> Two week internship doing x. This gave me experience in y and working with z etc.

If it was a very minor piece of work that doesn't help your CV look positive, you could just leave it out altogether.

Comment: thank you, it really helpful. Actually it's already in my CV I just wanted my CV to match what's in my linked In profile.